# CSS body Background

Tags: css, background

Hi I have a code like this:

```
body {  

background: rgb(59,103,158);
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 0%, rgba(43,136,217,1) 99%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(59,103,158,1)), color-stop(0%,rgba(125,185,232,1)), color-stop(99%,rgba(43,136,217,1))); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 99%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 99%); 
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 99%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 99%); 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3b679e', endColorstr='#2b88d9',GradientType=0 );

}
```

I got it straight from ColorZilla, but it repeats it self many times. I want it to be a background for a web page. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: "it repeats it self many times" as in displays the gradient many times or displays the gradient twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to prevent the background from repeating. For this, add

```
body { background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set background-size:

```
BODY {
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
       -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
         -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
            background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

(Will of course be applied to regular background, not to IE's filter.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually looking to reduce the amount of coding needed (as suggested by some), I would still stick with a 1px width image with repeat-x.

Less coding, cross-browser compatible, and i don't see that one image make such a huge difference in rendering time.

```
background: url('path_here/bg.jpg') repeat-x;
```